# Python Pivot table can not calculate total

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot

I am trying to get a total for rows and columns in this pivot table, but i keep getting an error, this is just an example of my code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Opret din DataFrame
data = {'Kolonne1': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'],
        'Kolonne2': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Z', 'Z']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
pivot_table = df.pivot_table(index='Kolonne1', columns='Kolonne2', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0, margins=True, margins_name='Totaler')

print(pivot_table)
```

But this just gives me "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"
if I remove ", margins=True, margins_name='Totaler'" I can get the pivot table but with out total

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

# Create your DataFrame
data = {'Kolonne1': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'],
        'Kolonne2': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Z', 'Z']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Use crosstab to create a pivot table with totals
pivot_table = pd.crosstab(df['Kolonne1'], df['Kolonne2'], margins=True, margins_name='Totaler')

print(pivot_table)

Kolonne2  X  Y  Z  Totaler
Kolonne1                  
A         2  0  0        2
B         0  1  1        2
C         0  0  1        1
Totaler   2  1  2        5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `margins` and `margins_name` parameters. you can  add the column and rows for the data frame.

```
pivot_table = df.pivot_table(index='Kolonne1', columns='Kolonne2', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)

pivot_table['Totaler'] = pivot_table.sum(axis=1)
pivot_table.loc['Totaler'] = pivot_table.sum()

print(pivot_table)
```

Output

```
Kolonne2  X  Y  Z  Totaler
Kolonne1
A         2  0  0        2
B         0  1  1        2
C         0  0  1        1
Totaler   2  1  2        5
```